# MyGeneration.dOOdads problem with MySQL connection in ASP.net with stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mygeneration

I am using MyGeneration.dOOdads which helps in generating Business layer and Data layer easily, but currently I am facing a problem with it.

I had worked with MS SQL database and was successful, but now I have to work with MySQL 5.

I have the generated data layer classes of MySQL database successfully, but when I add them in my project along with the reference of MyGeneration.dOOdads dll file it gives error of no `MySql4Entity` class in the namespace.

I have generated the class according to the given instructions and also added the reference of mysql.data in the project but still this error is occuring.

Please guide me if you have used MyGeneration.doodads for MYSQL5 database in asp.net.

Also please tell me how to make stored procedure using MyGeneration.doodads of MYSQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open doodads project (source code) .. right click on MySql4Entity class (and other classes related to mysql) and choose 'properties' the choose build action as 'compile' from the list ... to compile the file then build the project and it its output as reference to your project ...